# How to set CommandBar / AppBar to be always open

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I searched for a way, to set a commandBar (in a Windows Metro App) to be always open. But I couldn't find anything. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want it to ever close - simply use some `Panel` instead of the `AppBar`. If you use the `CommandBar` and utilize its infrastructure that automatically switches `IsCompact` property of the buttons - you could also try to handle the `Closed` event and set `IsOpen` to true. Also set `IsSticky` to true so you can use the rest of the UI.

Answer (score 2):

In UWP set the `IsOpen` and `IsSticky` to true on a `CommandBar`, and it should just stay open.

Comment: Not quite, clicking an `AppBarButton` will still close the `CommandBar`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the CommandBar add an event listener to 'closing':

```
        <CommandBar 
        x:Name="CommandBar"  
        IsSticky="True" 
        IsOpen="True" 
        OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" 
        LightDismissOverlayMode="Off"
        Closing="CommandBar_Closing">
```

So then in the xaml.cs code force it to stay open:

```
private void CommandBar_Closing(object sender, object e)
{
    CommandBar.IsOpen = true;
}
```